# Group of shift operators not uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X = \{ u \in C(\mathbb{R}) :  \lim_{t \rightarrow \pm \infty} u(t) = 0 \}$ with the supremum norm on X.

Given the operators $S(t): X \rightarrow X, u \mapsto S(t)u := u(\bullet -t)$, so S(t) is the rightshift operator.

I want to show that $(S(t))_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a group that is not uniformly continuous.

Uniform continuity on a group is defined as:

$ \Vert S(t) - Id \Vert_{L(X)}$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, where L(X) is the norm defined as $\sup_{u \in X} \frac{\Vert S(t)u \Vert_\infty}{\Vert u \Vert_\infty}$

Just by the definition I get:

$ \Vert S(t) - Id \Vert_{L(X)} = \sup_{u \in X} \frac{ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} | u(x-t) - u(x) |}{\sup_{x} |u(x)|}$

Now I guess it might be possible to choose some $u_0 \in X$ for which one can show that this is larger than some $\epsilon > 0$, but to me it seems as if this shouldn't be possible, since $u_0$ is supposed to be continuous. Can someone give some help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u$ be an element of $X$ whose supremum norm is $1$ . Define $u_n(x):= u(nx)$. Then for all $t$, 
$$
\left\lVert S(t)-\operatorname{Id}\right\rVert_X\geqslant \sup_{n\geqslant 1}\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}
\lvert u_n(x-t)-u_n(x)\rvert=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\lvert u(nx-nt)-u(nx)\rvert=\sup_{n\geqslant 1}
\sup_{x'\in\mathbb R}\lvert u(x'-nt)-u(x')\rvert 
$$
hence for each integer $N$, 
$$
\left\lVert S(t)-\operatorname{Id}\right\rVert_X\geqslant  \sup_{n\geqslant N}
\sup_{x \in\mathbb R}\lvert u(x -nt)-u( x)\rvert
\geqslant \sup_{n\geqslant N}
\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert u(x -nt)-u( x)\rvert\geqslant \sup_{n\geqslant N}\left(
\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert  u( x)\rvert -\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert  u( x-nt)\rvert\right).
$$
which gives, in view of $\sup_{n\geqslant N}\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert  u( x-nt)\rvert\leqslant \sup_{s\leqslant -Nt}\lvert  u( s)\rvert$ that 
$$
\left\lVert S(t)-\operatorname{Id}\right\rVert_X\geqslant\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert  u( x)\rvert -\sup_{s\leqslant -Nt}\lvert  u( s)\rvert
$$
for $t\gt 0$ and $N\geqslant 1$. Letting $N$ going to infinity shows that 
$$
\left\lVert S(t)-\operatorname{Id}\right\rVert_X\geqslant\sup_{x \lt 0}\lvert  u( x)\rvert.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. At first I thought I understood the last step, but actually I don't see how this is true. Can you please explain this step?

Comment: What do you call the last step? The justification of the last inequality?

Comment: Yes, I don't see why that is true.